# Azure Resource Manager NSG Port not responsive

Tags: azure, port, firewall

Issue: Port opened for VM in Azure Resource Manager is not working.

**Summary:**

- 1. Port has been open for a particular VM in Azure Resource Manager (Network Security Group)
- 2. But when we telnet the VM through another VM in the same subnet, it says connection failed.
- 3. I have also opened the specific port in Windows Server operating system firewall.
- 4. I then opened some random port for the VM in Azure Resource Manager (Network Security Group) and performed the above mentioned actions, but it failed.

Any recommendation on how to fix the issue?

Comment: Could you show how is it configured in the NSG?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure if you're using Telnet, that your firewall is open on the outbound server as source (* - all ports), and dest (your port).

When diagnosing, it might be best to turn off the windows firewalls so they're not a factor, get the NSG working, then put the windows firewalls back in.